# При попытке подключить payments к телеграмм боту выдает ошибку

Tags: java, spring, telegram-bot

код:

```
            List<LabeledPrice> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(new LabeledPrice("Онлайн консультация", 200));
            SendInvoice sendInvoice = new SendInvoice((int) chatId, "Кек", "Воу", "telebot-test-invoice",
                    "token", "pay", "RUB", list);

            InlineKeyboardMarkup inlineKeyboardMarkup = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();

            InlineKeyboardButton searchMaster = new InlineKeyboardButton().setText("Поиска мастера").setPay(true).setUrl("www.google.com");

            List<InlineKeyboardButton> keyboardButtonsRow1 = new ArrayList<>();
            keyboardButtonsRow1.add(searchMaster);

            List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> rowList = new ArrayList<>();
            rowList.add(keyboardButtonsRow1);

            inlineKeyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(rowList);

            sendInvoice.setReplyMarkup(inlineKeyboardMarkup);
            myWizardBot.execute(sendInvoice);
```

ошибка:

org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException: Error sending invoice
at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendInvoice.deserializeResponse(SendInvoice.java:338) ~[telegrambots-meta-4.4.0.2.jar:na]
at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendInvoice.deserializeResponse(SendInvoice.java:23) ~[telegrambots-meta-4.4.0.2.jar:na]
at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.sendApiMethod(DefaultAbsSender.java:725) ~[telegrambots-4.4.0.2.jar:na]
at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.bots.AbsSender.execute(AbsSender.java:47) ~[telegrambots-meta-4.4.0.2.jar:na]
at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.bots.AbsSender$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fdf401b0.invoke() ~[telegrambots-meta-4.4.0.2.jar:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:687) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at ru.home.mywizard_bot.MyWizardTelegramBot$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$288bd79d.execute() ~[main/:na]